# What is the data type of column_name in information_schema.columns?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

What is the data type of column_name in information_schema.columns?
i tried this but didnt get
code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_name_sunitest118(
    tbl character varying)

    RETURNS TABLE(column_name text) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

BEGIN

RETURN QUERY  

EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns where table_name=$1')

using tbl;

  END
  $BODY$;
```

Comment: In general you can use `pg_typeof()` to get that information:  `select pg_typeof(column_name) from information_schema.columns limit 1;`  the type is `sql_identifier`, and you can cast it to `text` with `column_name::text` in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can use `pg_typeof()` to get that information:

```
select pg_typeof(column_name) from information_schema.columns limit 1; 

┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│             pg_typeof             │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│ information_schema.sql_identifier │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

The type is `sql_identifier`, and you can cast it to `text` with `column_name::text` in your function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION table_name_sunitest118(
    tbl character varying)
    RETURNS TABLE(column_name text) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY  
  EXECUTE FORMAT(
    'SELECT column_name::text FROM information_schema.columns where table_name=$1'
  ) using tbl;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE FUNCTION

select * from table_name_sunitest118('users');
┌─────────────┐
│ column_name │
├─────────────┤
│ email       │
│ pass        │
│ role        │
│ id          │
│ email       │
└─────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, `describe information_schema.columns` says `varchar(64)`.

[The Postgres docs for the columns table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) says it is a [`sql_identifier`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-datatypes.html) defined as...

> A character string. This type is used for SQL identifiers, the type character_data is used for any other kind of text data.

Answer (score 0):

In `psql` you can use `\gdesc` command. It shows type on client side.

```
postgres=# select column_name from information_schema.columns \gdesc
┌─────────────┬──────┐
│   Column    │ Type │
╞═════════════╪══════╡
│ column_name │ name │
└─────────────┴──────┘
(1 row)
```

`pg_typeof` function shows type on server side

```
postgres=# select pg_typeof(column_name) from information_schema.columns limit 1;
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│             pg_typeof             │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ information_schema.sql_identifier │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```